# Extract a particular value of csv file without uploading whole file

Tags: python, csv

So I have a several tables in the format of csv, I am using Python and the csv module. I want to extract a particular value, lets say column=80 row=109.
Here is a random example:

```
import csv
with open('hugetable.csv', 'r') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    print(reader[109][80])
```

I am doing this many times with large tables and I would like to avoid loading the whole table into  an array (line 2 above) to ask for a single value. Is there a way to open the file, load the specific value and close it again? Would this process be more efficient than what I have done above?

Thanks for all the answers, all answers so far work pretty well.

Comment: If you are concerned about efficiency you should consider not using a CSV in the first place.  Something like a SQLite DB may be more appropriate for frequently updating individual values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try reading the file without csv library:

```
row = 108
column = 80
with open('hugetable.csv', 'r') as file:
    header = next(file)
    for _ in range(row-1):
        _ = next(file)
    line = next(file)
    print(line.strip().split(',')[column])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try pandas to load only certain columns of your csv file

```
import pandas as pd
pd.read_csv('foo.csv',usecols=["column1", "column2"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use pandas to load it

```
import pandas as pd

text = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv', sep=',', header=None, skiprows= 100, nrows=3)

print(text[50])
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, are the 100 and 50 here related to my example (109,80)?

Comment: No, they are just random numbers I came up with. 100 is how many rows it will skip, nrows is how many more rows it will load, and 50 is the column.